# How to send a message to a Channel from a Command

Tags: python, django, django-channels

How do you send a message to a Django Consumer from a custom manage.py command

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from channels import Channel

class Command(BaseCommand):
   help = 'Sends a message to a Django channel from the thing'

   def add_arguments(self, parser):
       parser.add_argument('json_object', nargs='+', type=str)

   def handle(self, *args, **options):
       self.stdout.write("TEST !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")


       print Channel("test").channel_layer
       Channel("test").send({'op':options['json_object'][0]})
```

This is my consumer

```
class MyConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

   @classmethod
   def channel_names(self):
      return {"test"}

   def connection_groups(self):
      return ["test"]

   def dispatch(self, message, **kwargs):
      return self.get_handler(message, **kwargs)(message, **kwargs)

  def get_handler(self, message, **kwargs):
          channel_routing = [
    consumers.MyConsumer.as_route(path=r"^/test/"),
    route("test.receive", consumers.chat_join),
]         for _filter, value in kwargs.items():
        filter_mapping = getattr(self, _filter + '_mapping', None)
        if not filter_mapping:
            continue

        consumer = getattr(self, filter_mapping.get(value), None)
        if consumer:
            return consumer
     raise ValueError('Message')


  def connect(self,message):
    self.message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})

  def receive(self,text=None, bytes= None):
    print text

  def disconnect(self,message):
    pass
```

When I try to run the command however, I get this message

> 2017-03-08 03:45:33,839 - ERROR - worker - Could not find match for message on test! Check your routing.

In case it is pertinent, here is my routing

```
channel_routing = [
    consumers.MyConsumer.as_route(path=r"^/test/"),
]
```

Comment: I have a very similar problem, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I actually created a custom version of the RedisChannelLayer and overrode those methods

Answer (score 1):

In short, add the `path` to the `content` you'd like to send:

```
Channel("test").send({
    'op':options['json_object'][0],
    'path': '/test/',
})
```

And that's it!

I ran into the same problem and I found out that it is because I am using the `as_route` method of generic consumer to generate `route_class`, which always has `path` as its filter.

If we use `route` instead we do not necessarily provide the `path` argument and that's the reason why the code at the doc (https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html#models) works